# Not Sure If I am using Rx Swift Correctly - BehaviorRelay Bind to TableView

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive

I am trying to update tableview via a delete button on my table cell class. But it doesn't update the tableview instantly which I don't know if it's too much to ask from behavior relay.

Properties:

```
private let businesses: BehaviorRelay<[StoresFeedModel]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [])

 var businessDataMain = [StoresFeedModel]()

 var businessDataFav = [StoresFeedModel]()
```

The button:

```
@objc func deleteTapped(_ sender: UIButton){

    
    deleteFavIdCoreData(id: storeid) //
 StoresFeed.shared.getFavDataforFavSegment()

   
}
```

The method that does the api call and updates the businessDataFav:

```
func getFavDataforFavSegment() {
    businesses.accept(businessDataFav)
    StoresTabCell.shared.fetchStoreIdCoreData()
    if StoresTabCell.shared.favIDsCoreData.removingDuplicates().count > 0  {
        for i in 0..<StoresTabCell.shared.favIDsCoreData.removingDuplicates().count {
            YelpAPIManager.shared.getFavStoreInfo(id: StoresTabCell.shared.favIDsCoreData.removingDuplicates()[i].favoriteStoreID!) { dataFav in
                self.businessDataFav = dataFav
            }
        }
    } else {
        businessDataFav = [StoresFeedModel(title: "No Favorites Yet", image: noValueImage, id: "No id yet")]
        return
    }
}
```

Binding method:

```
func bindTableViewMain() {
    businesses.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView
                .rx
                .items(cellIdentifier: storesFeedCellId, cellType: StoresTabCell.self)
        )
    {
        row, businessData, cell in

        cell.configureWithData(dataModel: businessData)
    }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I have two segments on the main view:

```
@objc func actionofSC() {
    let type = segments[segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
    switch type {
    case .allStores:
    getMainData()

    case .favorites:
    getFavDataforFavSegment()
        
    }
}
```

Now what I want is the update of TableView while I am browsing on favorites segment and hit the delete button. I am keeping the favorite ids on core data. So the delete or fav buttons actually first updates the core data entity and then I am doing the api call via those ids. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are all of your code blocks in the same class or different classes?

Comment: Can you post a minimal compilable sample?

Comment: @DanielT. the button func is in the TableView Cell class.

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough. Please post a simplified example that compiles.

Comment: @DanielT. can I share a github link ? otherwise I will work on simplifying because this has login pages etc.

Comment: If you must. But it’s better if you can post a small sample that just has the code you are having a problem with.

Comment: This is the github link https://github.com/ipanzerkampfwagen/dealApp.git but all you need to do is to check the button and why it doesn't change the value of relay. It is in the cell class